# SQL Server 2016 - How to do a simple pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I looked at many other examples but they always have some sort of `AVG` or `SUM` in their pivot query. And I can't figure out how to apply it in my case. There are many examples out there, but I couldn't get it to work. What's wrong with my query?

I'm just looking to pivot my table (query: `SELECT LevelName, ParentNodeName from vOrgStructurePath  where orgstructureid = 1545`):

```
+---+-----------+----------------+
|   | LevelName | ParentNodeName |
+---+-----------+----------------+
| 1 | Level1    | Rough          |
+---+-----------+----------------+
| 2 | Level2    | Soft           |
+---+-----------+----------------+
```

To this:

```
+---+--------+--------+
|   | Level1 | Level2 |
+---+--------+--------+
| 1 | Rough  | Soft   |
+---+--------+--------+
```

Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT LevelName, ParentNodeName from vOrgStructurePath 
 PIVOT (LevelName for ParentNodeName IN ([Level1],[Level2])) as level
 where orgstructureid = 1545
```

But it's getting this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'.
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All kinds of pivot require conditional aggregation. That's the only way for your RDBMS needs to gather multiple lines into one.

Some RDBMS provide vendor-specific functions that implement the pivot logic (SQL Server is one of them, just like Oracle is). But they are basically just syntaxic sugar on top of the base idea, which always boils down to conditional aggregation.

I usually advocate against these vendor specific implementations, since there is little gain in the query complexity, and a big loss in portability (and readability, unless you are an expert in that specific language).

Here is a standard solution to pivot data, that will work across most, if not all RDBMS:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN LevelName = 'Level1' THEN ParentNodeName END) as [Level1],
    MAX(CASE WHEN LevelName = 'Level2' THEN ParentNodeName END) as [Level2]
FROM vOrgStructurePath 
WHERE orgstructureid = 1545
```

You can easily have this query process multiple `orgstructureid` at once, by changing it as follows:

```
SELECT
    orgstructureid,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LevelName = 'Level1' THEN ParentNodeName END) as [Level1],
    MAX(CASE WHEN LevelName = 'Level2' THEN ParentNodeName END) as [Level2]
FROM vOrgStructurePath 
GROUP BY orgstructureid
```

This generates one record per `orgstructureid`, along with its `Level1` and `Level2` values.

Comment: This is amazing, I'm still trying to figure out how this works exactly, but it works! so much more portable.