# Do something similar to PIVOT by using CASE instead?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, case, sql-server-2016

I have a column named '**typetxt**' that has '**Late Reason**' and '**Notes**' (and other values that I don't care about). My current query has a case statement to select only '**Late Reason**' and '**Notes**' and sets everything else to **NULL**.

I have another column named '**detail_value**' that contains a text value for either '**Late Reason**' or '**Notes**'. All values of '**typetxt/detail_value**' are **varchar(50)**.

This is what it looks like:

| typetxt | detail_value |
| --- | --- |
| Late Reason | This is a late reason |
| Notes | This is a note |

Here is the part of the query I am currently working on. I do a couple of joins before this and 3 more joins after this part of the query:

```
SELECT [id], [rowid], [start_date], [data_type], [detail_value], 
       [typetxt]  = CASE
             WHEN typetxt = 'Late Reason' 
                  or typetxt= 'Notes' THEN typetxt
             ELSE NULL
            END,
       FROM mytable MT
       WHERE [start_date] IS NOT NULL AND [data_type] = 'SAS'
```

Is there any way to add a temp column or something similar without using PIVOT so that resulting table looks like this?

| Late Reason | Notes |
| --- | --- |
| This is a Late Reason | NULL |
| NULL | This is a note |

If I have to use PIVOT (or dynamic pivot) can you add this into the above code? I have tried

```
...
       FROM mytable MT
       WHERE [start_date] IS NOT NULL AND [data_type] = 'SAS' 
       PIVOT (
       *not sure what to put here* FOR 'Late Reason' IN (typetxt, detail_value)      
       ) as Late_Reason
```

Searched some more and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035879/sql-server-2016-how-to-do-a-simple-pivot)

And tried adding

```
 MAX(CASE WHEN [typetxt] = 'Late Reason' THEN [detail_value] END) as [Late_Reason],
 MAX(CASE WHEN [typetxt] = 'Notes' THEN [detail_value] END) as [Notes]
```

In place of PIVOT in the above code but got "*invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause*" error message.

Tried adding a GROUP BY in this part of my query but no luck.

I am not familiar with PIVOT and have looked it up quite extensively (well maybe this proves not super deep ahah) but I just can't understand this part. Thanks for any advice/help.

Comment: *"invalid in the select list"* **what** is invalid? Those 2 expressions are in the aggregate functions.

Comment: says my "typetxt" is invalid in the select list. Not really sure what it means by that am looking into what that is referring to. Might be I am just missing the point on that error message.

Comment: Presumably you also have it not aggregates. A snippet of a statement does t tell us the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Was using

```
 MAX(CASE WHEN [typetxt] = 'Late Reason' THEN [detail_value] END) as [Late_Reason],
 MAX(CASE WHEN [typetxt] = 'Notes' THEN [detail_value] END) as [Notes]
```

in the wrong place.

This should have gone up at the top of my query where I do:

`SELECT [var1], [var2], [var3], etc`
and not in my actual query shown above if that makes sense.